# How to check time range between multiple time range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

i have schedule data for assign driver to the user in excel..
here's my data:

[image]

All i want to know is how to check time range between other time range (without macro) so i can create a new schedule for the driver if possible..

for example, if some user make request on 24/12/2014 at 11:00 to 12:00, i can assign driver A to do that, because between 11.00 to 12.00, Driver A doesn't have any schedule for delivery.. and if i assign Driver A on 11:00 to 13:00, it will show me not available status because they have delivery schedule on 12:00 to 14:00..

does anyone know how to that? many thanks..

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know when the driver started & finished their shift? e.g. what about 15:00 - 16:00 ?

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways of doing it, but have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the example slightly to limit it to just a named driver. Your drivers don't seem to need any breaks between their jobs so you just want to find any existing slots which overlap with your proposed slot and it looks like this:-

(1) Beginning of existing slot before end of proposed slot

```
F$9:F$12,"<"&G14
```

and

(2) End of existing slot after beginning of proposed slot

```
G$9:G$12,">"&F14
```

and

(3) Same driver

```
E$9:E$12,E14
```

Putting all this together using COUNTIFS and placing this in an IF statement in H14:-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(F$9:F$12,"<"&G14,G$9:G$12,">"&F14,E$9:E$12,E14),"Not available","Available")
```

and pull down to H15.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom.. yes, i've tried to do that since 2 days ago.. and i have no idea how to compare single value in a range of cells and now i know that we can use "<"[Cells] to do that.. Many thanks for your helps.. :)